# How to check in python rabbitmq if messages not delivered in last 5 seconds

Tags: python, rabbitmq, queue

Hello im trying to write code in python with rabbitmq. I have an queue where i send messages but i have to check on the consumer if message have been sent in last 5 seconds and if not i should terminate the process. I tryied to search the internet for such function but there is no relevant answer, can you suggest me something guys?

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ includes a heartbeat to detect unresponsive peers/failed messages

[From the docs:](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html)

> Detecting Dead TCP Connections with Heartbeats
>
> In some types of network failure, packet loss can mean that disrupted
>   TCP connections take a moderately long time (about 11 minutes with
>   default configuration on Linux, for example) to be detected by the
>   operating system. AMQP 0-9-1 offers a heartbeat feature to ensure that
>   the application layer promptly finds out about disrupted connections
>   (and also completely unresponsive peers). Heartbeats also defend
>   against certain network equipment which may terminate "idle" TCP
>   connections.

To enable [Hearbeats](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html) with Java Client :

```
ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();

// set the heartbeat timeout to 5 seconds
cf.setRequestedHeartbeat(5);
```

Similarly with .NET Client:

```
var cf = new ConnectionFactory();

// set the heartbeat timeout to 5 seconds
cf.RequestedHeartbeat = 5;
```

Hope this helps.

(there's more about [dead-letter exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) in the rabbitmq docs, also about the nack and ack/(neg/pos) delivery/confirms [on this page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) but configuring Heartbeats should do the trick.)

EDIT: Sorry, there's also a [python remote procedure callback example](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) in the docs! It requires ['pika'](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/examples/blocking_publish_mandatory.html)..  missed that!

Server Code Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='rpc_queue')

def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def on_request(ch, method, props, body):
    n = int(body)

    print(" [.] fib(%s)" % n)
    response = fib(n)

    ch.basic_publish(exchange='',
                     routing_key=props.reply_to,
                     properties=pika.BasicProperties(correlation_id = \
                                                         props.correlation_id),
                     body=str(response))
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(on_request, queue='rpc_queue')

print(" [x] Awaiting RPC requests")
channel.start_consuming()
```

Client Code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import uuid

class FibonacciRpcClient(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))

        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

        result = self.channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
        self.callback_queue = result.method.queue

        self.channel.basic_consume(self.on_response, no_ack=True,
                                   queue=self.callback_queue)

    def on_response(self, ch, method, props, body):
        if self.corr_id == props.correlation_id:
            self.response = body

    def call(self, n):
        self.response = None
        self.corr_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                                   routing_key='rpc_queue',
                                   properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                         reply_to = self.callback_queue,
                                         correlation_id = self.corr_id,
                                         ),
                                   body=str(n))
        while self.response is None:
            self.connection.process_data_events()
        return int(self.response)

fibonacci_rpc = FibonacciRpcClient()

print(" [x] Requesting fib(30)")
response = fibonacci_rpc.call(30)
print(" [.] Got %r" % response)
```